# WordPress Loop for video category(template) not working on all browsers

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, video, categories

I'm developing a template to display videos in a tiled sort of fashion. The loop I've created is meant to grab all posts with the category of "video". I've also tried this with format-type of video, and a template based on taxonomy-post-format-post-video.php, but with the same results:

Basically, the loop works fine in certain browsers (Safari 8) but actually fails to get any posts from the query in other browsers. (mainly mobile browsers, and IE).

When the loop is working, I get an expected single video. When it is not, I get the error "Sorry, no videos found...." - Same code, different browsers, different results.

Here is a link to an example of this behavior: http://www.enableart.org/langschwartzwald/wordpress/blog/category/video/

and here is the code:

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=video'); ?>

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="video_tile">
            <?php the_content();
                the_id(); ?>
            <div class="video_title">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<br>
    <h1 style="color: lightblue;"><?php _e( 'Sorry, no videos found...' ); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Put `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` inside `wp-config.php` to see the errors.

Comment: I added this to my wp-config.php file, but it did not generate any errors on the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with Your markup, it should be:

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=video');?>
<!-- the loop -->
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="video_tile">
            <?php the_content();
                the_id(); ?>
            <div class="video_title">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<br>
    <h1 style="color: lightblue;"><?php _e( 'Sorry, no videos found...' ); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

basically `<!-- the loop -->` comment type is not allowed in php and it messes things up (I guess)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Were were correct in spotting the missing closing tag.  But even with that back in, and all the comment removed, the issue is still not resolved.   Any other ideas?